# Why does this fiber behaves this way

Tags: ruby, fiber

In this code:

```
fiber = Fiber.new do |first, second|
  num = Fiber.yield first + second + 2
end

puts fiber.resume 5, 4
puts fiber.resume 3
```

The output is `11` and `3` each on a separate line.

I understand why the output is `11` for the first `fiber.resume` (its parameters are passed as block arguments to `Fiber.new`) but I don't understand why the second `fiber.resume` returns `3`. What's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation:

> The Fiber#resume method accepts an arbitrary number of parameters, if
>   it is the first call to resume then they will be passed as block
>   arguments. Otherwise they will be the return value of the call to
>   Fiber.yield

Your second call to resume is only returning the value returned by Fiber#yield, which would be simply 3.

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Fiber.html